# Amazon MWS C# Products GetCompetitivePricingForSKU throws Exception

Tags: c#, amazon-mws

When I'm trying to Request the Competettive Price for a Product i always get a

`MarketplaceWebServiceProductsException`

The Message is empty, and the TargetSite gives me

`T Call[T](MWSClientCsRuntime.IMwsRequestType1[T], MWSClientCsRuntime.IMwsObject)`

Here is the Code I'm running

```cs
        MarketplaceWebServiceProducts.MarketplaceWebServiceProducts service = new MarketplaceWebServiceProductsClient (config.MWS_AccessKeyId, config.MWS_secretKey);

        SellerSKUListType list = new SellerSKUListType ();

        List<String> SKUList = new List<String> ();
        SKUList.Add (SKU);

        list.SellerSKU = SKUList;

        GetCompetitivePricingForSKURequest request = new GetCompetitivePricingForSKURequest ();

        request.MarketplaceId = config.MWS_MarketPlaceId;
        request.SellerId = config.MWS_SellerId;
        request.SellerSKUList = list;

        GetCompetitivePricingForSKUResponse response = service.GetCompetitivePricingForSKU (request);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to specify application name and application version?

```
var config = new MarketplaceWebServiceProductsConfig();
config.ServiceURL = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01";
config.SetUserAgent(ApplicationName, ApplicationVersion);

var service = new MarketplaceWebServiceProductsClient(ApplicationName, ApplicationVersion, MWSaccessKey, MWSsecretKey, config);
```